# Drug Analyzer challenge

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

**What do I need help with?**

I'm doing the challenge below, in which I need to increase code performance. It's currently at 63% and I need to increase it to at least 71% however I can't optimize more than the current one.
How can it be optimized?

> **Introduction**
>
> You are a member of a biotechnology programming team that is
> responsible for creating a system for lab technicians, which will
> assist them with drug analysis.
>
> Your goal is to create the application that will let them input their
> findings into the system, provide a meaningful analysis and verify the
> correctness of the data that they have sent.
>
> **Prerequisites**
>
> To complete this task, use `Python 3`.
>
> **Task Details**
>
> Note: Please do *NOT* modify any tests unless specifically told to do so.
>
> #### Part 1
>
> Your goal in this part is to implement the
> `app.drug_analyzer.DrugAnalyzer` class. It will be responsible for
> analyzing data like the data presented below:
>
> | pill_id | pill_weight | active_substance | impurities |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | L01-10 | 1007.67 | 102.88 | 1.00100 |
> | L01-06 | 996.42 | 99.68 | 2.00087 |
> | G02-03 | 1111.95 | 125.04 | 3.00004 |
> | G03-06 | 989.01 | 119.00 | 4.00062 |
>
> - The initialization of the class can be done from Python's list of lists (or nothing) and stored in the instance
>   variable called `data` as per example below:
>
> ```
> >> my_drug_data = [
> ...                 ['L01-10', 1007.67, 102.88, 1.00100],
> ...                 ['L01-06', 996.42, 99.68, 2.00087],
> ...                 ['G02-03', 1111.95, 125.04, 3.00100],
> ...                 ['G03-06', 989.01, 119.00, 4.00004]
> ... ]
> >>> my_analyzer = DrugAnalyzer(my_drug_data)
> >>> my_analyzer.data
> [['L01-10', 1007.67, 102.88, 0.001],
> ... ['L01-06', 996.42, 99.68, 0.00087],
> ... ['G02-03', 1111.95, 125.04, 0.00100],
> ... ['G03-06', 989.01, 119.00, 0.00004]]
> >>> DrugAnalyzer().data
> []
> ```
>
> - The class should also have an option to add single lists into the object. Adding a list to the `DrugAnalyzer` object
>   should return a new instance of this object with an additional element. Adding improper type or a list with improper
>   length should raise a `ValueError`. An example of a correct and wrong addition output is shown below:
>
> ```
> >>> my_new_analyzer = my_analyzer + ['G03-01', 789.01, 129.00, 0.00008]
> >>> my_new_analyzer.data
> [['L01-10', 1007.67, 102.88, 0.001], 
> ... ['L01-06', 996.42, 99.68, 0.00087], 
> ... ['G02-03', 1111.95, 125.04, 0.00100], 
> ... ['G03-06', 989.01, 119.00, 0.00004], 
> ... ['G03-01', 789.01, 129.00, 0.00008]]
> >>> my_new_analyzer = my_analyzer + ['G03-01', 129.00, 0.00008]
> Traceback (the most recent call is displayed as the last one):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ValueError: Improper length of the added list.
> ```
>
> #### Part 2
>
> Implement the `verify_series` method inside the `app.drug_analyzer.DrugAnalyzer` class.
>
> The goal of this method is to receive a list of parameters and use
> them to verify if the pills described inside the instance variable
> `data` matches the given criteria. It should return a `Boolean` value
> as a result.
>
> The function would be called as follows:
>
> ```
> verify_series(series_id = 'L01', act_subst_wgt = 100, act_subst_rate = 0.05, allowed_imp = 0.001)
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> - the `series_id` is a 3 characters long string that is present at the beginning of every `pill_id`, before the `-` sign, for example, `L01` is the `series_id` in `pill_id = L01-12`.
> - the `act_subst_wgt` is the expected weight (*mg*) of the active substance content in the given series in one pill.
> - the `act_subst_rate` is the allowed rate of difference in the active substance weight from the expected one. For example,
>   for `100 mg`, the accepted values would be between `95` and `105`.
> - the `allowed_imp` is the allowed rate of impure substances in the `pill_weight`. For example, for `1000 mg` pill_weight
>   and `0.001` rate, the allowed amount of impurities is `1 mg`.
>
> The function should take all pills that are part of the `L01` series, sum their weight and calculate if the amount of `active_substance`, as well as `impurities`, match the given rates. It should return `True` if both conditions are met and `False` if any of them is not met.
>
> The `False` result should mean that all the passed parameters are proper, but either the `active_substance` amount or the `impurities` amount is improper.
> In case of a `series_id` that is not present in the `data` at all or in case of any improper parameter, the function should throw a `ValueError`.
> Please think what could be the possible edge case in such a scenario.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> >>> my_drug_data = [
> ...                 ['L01-10', 1000.02, 102.88, 1.00100],
> ...                 ['L01-06', 999.90, 96.00, 2.00087],
> ...                 ['G02-03', 1000, 96.50, 3.00100],
> ...                 ['G03-06', 989.01, 119.00, 4.00004]
> ... ]
> >>> my_analyzer = DrugAnalyzer(my_drug_data)
> >>> my_analyzer.verify_series(series_id = 'L01', act_subst_wgt = 100, act_subst_rate = 0.05, allowed_imp = 0.001)
> False
> >>> // The overall active_substances weight would be 198.88, which is within the given rate of 0.05 for 200 mg (2 * act_subst_wgt).
> >>> // However, the sum of impurities would be 3.00187, which is more than 0.001*1999.92 (allowed_imp_rate * (1000.02 + 999.90).
> >>> my_analyzer.verify_series(series_id = 'L01', act_subst_wgt = 100, act_subst_rate = 0.05, allowed_imp = 0.0001)
> True
> >>> my_analyzer.verify_series(series_id = 'B03', act_subst_wgt = 100, act_subst_rate = 0.05, allowed_imp = 0.001)
> Traceback (the most recent call is displayed as the last one):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ValueError: B03 series is not present within the dataset.
> ```

#### My Code:

```
class DrugAnalyzer:
    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(self.data[0]) != len(other):
            raise ValueError('Improper length of the added list.')

        if type(other[0]) is not str or type(other[1]) is not float or type(other[2]) is not float or type(other[3]) is not float:
            raise ValueError('Wrong type.')

        total_data = self.data
        total_data.append(other)
        return DrugAnalyzer(total_data)

    def verify_series(
        self,
        series_id: str,
        act_subst_wgt: float,
        act_subst_rate: float,
        allowed_imp: float,
    ) -> bool:
    
        lists = list(filter(lambda k: series_id in k[0], self.data))
        pills_weight = sum([liste[1] for liste in lists])
        actives_substances = sum([liste[2] for liste in lists])
        impurities = sum([liste[3] for liste in lists])

        if (len(lists) * act_subst_wgt * (1 + act_subst_rate)) > actives_substances > (len(lists) * act_subst_wgt * (1 - act_subst_rate)):
            if impurities < (allowed_imp * pills_weight):
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: This fails but should succeed: `my_analyzer = DrugAnalyzer(); my_new_analyzer = my_analyzer + ['G03-01', 789.01, 129.00, 0.00008]`

Comment: This returns a value, but should raise an exception: `DrugAnalyzer().verify_series('L01', 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Does the problem specify any limits on the size of various inputs. That is, how many different pill_id's, series_id's, additions, or calls to verify_series?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. Brainly's recruitment? For content not originated by you, please [tell who did and where you encountered it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) - hyperlinks welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `__init__` has a mutable default argument. The default argument is *not* reset between calls to a function, so multiple analyzers that start out empty will have *the same* list, which could be a problem if one of them changes:

  ```py
  >>> a1 = DrugAnalyzer()
  >>> a1.data.append(['G03-01', 789.01, 129.00, 0.00008])
  >>> a2 = DrugAnalyzer()
  >>> a2.data
  [['G03-01', 789.01, 129.0, 8e-05]]
  ```

  One option to avoid that could be explicitly copying the argument's content to a new list, perhaps like

  ```
  def __init__(self, drug_data=None):
      self.data = []
      if drug_data:
          self.data[:] = drug_data
  ```
- It feels weird that `__add__` verifies the shape of its input, but `__init__` doesn't. Especially since the pre-existing data is used to decide whether a list is valid to add with `__add__` - what if someone did `DrugAnalyzer([[]])`? Then you could only add 0-length lists to that analyzer, and a 0-length list will never pass the type check!
- By the way, the reason I used `a1.data.append` instead of `+=` earlier? `__add__` does not work on empty `DrugAnalyzer`s - it tries to get `self.data[0]`, which won't work if `self.data` is empty
- `__add__` modifies `self.data`. Try:

  ```py
  >>> a1 = DrugAnalyzer([['G03-01', 789.01, 129.00, 0.00008]])
  >>> a2 = a1 + ['G02-03', 1111.95, 125.04, 3.00100]
  >>> a1.data
  [['G03-01', 789.01, 129.0, 8e-05], ['G02-03', 1111.95, 125.04, 3.001]]
  ```

  This is because both the old and new analyzer share the *same* list. You probably want to explicitly create a new list instead - `total_data = self.data + [other]` could be one way to do that
- The `if` in `verify_series` is annoyingly long. I would consider at least calculating `len(lists) * act_subst_weight)` in advance and going `if target_weight * (1 + act_subst_rate) > active_substances > (1 - act_subst_rate)`. Or perhaps something like `actual_rate = actives_substances / act_subst_weight` followed by `if (1 + act_subst_rate) > actual_rate > (1 - act_subst_rate)`
- `verify_series` does not throw a `ValueError` for non-existing pill series' as the requirements demand, but instead returns `False`
- `verify_series` may mis-identify pills as belonging to the wrong pill series - if I understand the requirements correctly, `G03-06` should *only* belong to the `G03` series, not `G0`, `06` or `3-0`, but this implementation will count it as being part of all those. Something like `series_id == k[0].split('-')[0]` or `k[0].startswith(series_id + "-")` might be more robust

Comment: Wow, very good, it helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider validating all entries and throwing errors for invalid data. Once all inputs are tested.

Comment: For a programming-challenge, it is implied that all data is valid. It is a controlled environment and one of the few situations in which case input-validation is a waste of resources.

Comment: It is not implied. This is one of the tests.